# how to build automation tests using selenium in java that supports Right to left language like arabic ? any code examples

Tags: java, selenium, localization, automation, internationalization

I have a website which supports both arabic and english language and might support more language later .. and for sure i dont want to build automation tests for each language .. for now i have done the automation for the english and trying to do automation tests for the arabic language the problem is the alignment of the entire websites pages changes to be from right to legt how to solve the locators alignments .. how can i build a generic automation tests to run on any language ??
code examples and resources needed plz

[HTML example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b8zgp.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think HTML layout should not change with alignment change (only CSS change). So you are safe to use XPATH and ID locator, try to avoid using CSS selectors because they may change depends on alignment of website. You should also be careful when you use CLASS NAME, I suppose some change when alligment is changed.

Could you please upload some example of HTML which you test?. It would help.

Comment: yes you are right :)  i tried out using xpath only and alignments didnt change, However i need to support multi language with the same code if possible ... Now that i have done it in english i need to do it in 2 more language some forums claim using properties file but no further details included .. any idea how can i start supporting another language with same code ? --- html example attached in post

Comment: Can you specify what exactly you want to test? some example, you want also want to test content of the website (which change with the language)

Comment: yes exactly i want to test the content that change with the language .. for ex: page titles, titles in navigation bar, Menu items text ....etc .. i need to do automation for the internationalization as the website will support multiple languages ... i have already done in english now i need to do arabic content .. ithere is a way where i only change a properties file for each language .. check this article 
https://nileshdk.wordpress.com/2013/08/06/internationalization-automating-localized-ui-using-selenium-webdriver/?blogsub=confirming#subscribe-blog